# How to programmatically calculate NCD for Markov Chain

Tags: python, math, markov-chains

Basically, I need to calculate Decomposability index for Markov Chains and found this [article](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Markov_chain,_decomposable) which defines decomposability, but I completely don't know how could I calculate that or what package I could use in python.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am think you should take a look at http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/

CRFSuite come with a lot of examples in Python.

Comment: Could you, please, give me an example how I could calculate it using this tool?